# How to use Hibernate Full Text Search

Tags: hibernate, struts

I am developing an application in struts 1.2 framework.

I want to use hibernate full text search in my application.
How can I use it?

Comment: Reading the documentation would be a start. Or did you have a more specific question?

Comment: ok I"ll notice it for further answers but right now i need the answers.............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the book [Hibernate Search in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988649).
IMHO, it is very useful for both beginners and professionals.